# Angular.js ng-repeat no data using json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a project I am working on where I have a json array (that will later come from a web service)

and I am trying to use ng-repeat to load that data into a table. (I have done this before, this time it's just slipping paste me what I am missing)

I posted the code to github here: https://github.com/sheets/Sch

I'd love any help I am posting the code here as well:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="SchCtrl">

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <th width="15%">Date and Time</th>
        <th width="50%">Provider</th>
        <th width="15%">Location</th>
        <th width="10%">Map</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="appointment in appointments | orderBy:'startDatetime':true">
            {{appointments.startDatetime | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'}}
            {{appointments.providerName}}
{{appointments.apptLocation}}</tr></tbody></table>


</div>
</body>
```

and app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("SchCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/appointments.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.appointments = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
});
```

Comment: For one thing... you have no `<td>`.

Comment: Removed for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [this simple exaple](http://plnkr.co/edit/kl52uOuzo2gyEUSLFoaY?p=preview)
1. You need to wrap all your data in TD tags
2. To access your data - you need to do that like `data.appointments`
3. In `ng-repeat` you need to access every item in your *appointments* array - so that is `appointment`

Answer (score 3):

Try accessing `appointment.startDatetime` instead of `appointments.startDatetime`. Same for `providerName` and `apptLocation`. Basically remove the `s` in appointments.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be

```
$scope.appointments = data.appointments
```

?
And then you have to access

```
appointment.<field_name>
```